# Can I preserve the database file during an app update?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to programming cocoa apps so please be patient if this is a stupid question.

I am setting up a database with the core framework. My app will have frequent updates and bug fixes. How can I prevent that an update of my application overwrites the database? Can I update everything BUT the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the application will overwrite only the application bundle (i.e. Yourprogram.app folder). It will not do anything with ~/Library/ and ~/Documents, where all your databases should be stored.

Comment: do i have to specify where the database are stored or will they automatically be stored there?

Comment: No. It is by default stored at ~/Library/Containers/com.yourcompany.yourAppName/ for sandboxed application, and most likely at ~/Library/Application Support for non-sandboxed